# GAE Java automatic scaling min-idle-instances not working?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, autoscaling

I have Java GAE app with modules. Default front-end module is marked as

```
<automatic-scaling>
  <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
</automatic-scaling>
```

however when I check chart of instances for last 24 hours, I see that there is a period where no instance was running. I'd expect that `min-idle-instances` would set minimal number of running instances.

Is `min-idle-instances` not working ? Or is instance chart not working ? (By instance chart I mean chart accessible from Dashboad). Or do I get concept of `min-idle-instances` wrong?

Current GAE version is 1.9.11

Answer (score 2):

I actually ran into similar questions regarding min-idle-instances.  Turns out the min-idle-instance isn't EXACTLY what it sounds like.

I don't know for your project, but for us, the min actually meant it wouldn't STOP instances to go lower than min.  It can still have fewer instances running.

Example (with 5 min idle instances).

0 running instances -> enough requests to boot up 3 instances -> requests finish, still at 3 instances -> more request that now need 6 instances -> requests finish, one instance spins down, we are now at our minimum and won't go lower.

Is it something like that you experience or is your instance actually spinning down?

[EDIT] The actual problem in this case had to do with maximum daily budgets. When the budget was hit, the instance went down to save costs.

Comment: i've noticed that in our case total budget was pretty low, so i presume GAE has shut down all instances as we ran out of budget. i don't see how to verify my hypothesis though :(

Comment: ok so your instance actually spins down..... hmmmm do you have a maximum daily budget? that definitely would spin instances down

Comment: yeah, there is max daily budget, that must be it.

Comment: @michalsankot I just edited my answer to include that, to make sure that it is seen by users searching a similar issue :) thanx for confirming it

Comment: i can't really confirm it. it's what we believe that hapened. unfortunatelly GAE doesn't provide means to verify that it really is what happened. unless there is something in console/admin pages that i've missed.